# Prolog Partial Matching

Tags: prolog

If there is a rule that cannot be satisfied with all parameters, is there a standard way to get a partial match with just some of the parameters?

For example, the following query can not find a solution:

```
?- query(A, B, C).
false.
```

But a solution can be found if we don't try to unify on C:

```
?- query_best_effort(A, B, C).
A = alfa,
B = bravo ;
```

I have the following code that implements this functionality.  But is there a more Prolog-way to do this?

```
fact1(alfa).
fact2(bravo).
fact3(charlie).

rule1(A) :-
    fact1(A).

rule2(B) :-
    fact2(B).

rule3(C) :-
    fact3(C),
    C \== charlie.

query(A, B, C) :-
    rule1(A),
    rule2(B),
    rule3(C).

query_best_effort(A, B, C) :-
    query_chain3(A, B, C);
    query_chain2(A, B);
    query_chain1(A).

query_chain3(A, B, C) :-
    query(A, B, C).

query_chain2(A, B) :-
    \+query_chain3(A, B, _),
    rule1(A),
    rule2(B).

query_chain1(A) :-
    \+query_chain2(A, _),
    rule1(A).
```

Comment: You are using non-logical constructs (negation by failure `\+` and syntactic inequality `\==`). They usually destroy the logical properties of your program (define e.g. `p(something).` then `\+ p(X).` is false but the instance `\+ X = other, p(X)` is true). In most cases, you actually want `dif/2` instead of `\==` (e.g. look at the result of `A \== B`). Negation can often be avoided by reformulating the problem.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if you need negation, chances are good there's an error somewhere (because negation is really hard to handle). I usually recommend to read O'Keefe: The Craft of Prolog before using negation.

Comment: One limited way of having negation is to accumulate results and use a predicate `nonmember_of(Element, List)` built over [`dif/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dif/2).-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, a comment on programming style. When using disjunctions (`;/2`), **always** wrap them between parenthesis and avoid writing `;` at the end of a line. In your case:

```
query_best_effort(A, B, C) :-
    (   query_chain3(A, B, C)
    ;   query_chain2(A, B)
    ;   query_chain1(A)
    ).
```

This recommended style contributes to code readability.

You can also avoid using negation (`\+/1`) by using instead the `*->/2` *soft-cut* control construct implemented in several Prolog systems (a few systems, e.g. SICStus Prolog, implement it as an `if/3` built-in predicate):

```
query_best_effort(A, B, C) :-
    (   query_chain3(A, B, C) *->
        true
    ;   query_chain2(A, B) *->
        true
    ;   query_chain1(A)
    ).

query_chain3(A, B, C) :-
    query(A, B, C).

query_chain2(A, B) :-
    rule1(A),
    rule2(B).

query_chain1(A) :-
    rule1(A).
```

The `*->/2` control construct, unlike the standard `->/2` control construct, allows backtracking into the condition. When calling the `query_best_effort/3` predicate, the `query_chain2/2` predicate will only be called if there are no solutions for the `query_chain3/3` goal and the `query_chain1/1` predicate will only be called if there are no solutions for the `query_chain3/3` and `query_chain2/2` goals, which I assume was your intention with the use of disjunction and negation?

Sample call:

```
| ?- query_best_effort(A, B, C).

A = alfa
B = bravo
yes
```

Note, however, that `*->/2` is, like negation, a non-logical control construct.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes that was my intent.  In general, my use case is:If running the query with all N parameters does not produce any solutions, try the query with the first N-1 parameters.  And if that does not produce any solutions, try with the first N-2 parameters and so on..."